# cannot delete std::vector & std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

My C++ class has a destructor that tries to delete std::vector and std::array instance variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> foo;
    std::vector< std::array<float, 4> > vertices;

    foo[0] = 1;
    foo[1] = 2;
    foo[2] = 3;
    std::cout << foo[0] << std::endl;
    delete foo;
    delete vertices;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure how to properly free up the memory - how come I can't delete those variables?

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Weverything ccc.cpp 
ccc.cpp:14:2: error: cannot delete expression of type 'std::array<int, 3>'
        delete foo;
        ^      ~~~
ccc.cpp:15:2: error: cannot delete expression of type 'std::vector<std::array<float, 4>
      >'
        delete vertices;
        ^      ~~~~~~~~
ccc.cpp:18:2: warning: C++98 requires newline at end of file [-Wc++98-compat-pedantic]
}
 ^
```

Comment: You didn't allocate anything with `new`, why do you feel the urge to deallocate something with `delete`? These are automatic variables - they are destroyed automatically when they go out of scope.

Comment: even if they are member instance variables in a class?

Comment: Yes, members of a class don't have a hidden `new` attached.

Comment: They are not class members in the code you show. Anyway, the lifetime of non-static class members matches that of the containing class instance.

Comment: @ejang: Firstly, what happens "in a class" is none of your business, to put it bluntly. The class itself will take care of everything, if the class is properly designed. Secondly, `std::array` does not allocate any memory dynamically "in a class". `std::vector` does, but again, it is not for you to worry about.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Delete these variables? The only "variables" you should `delete` are the ones you allocated by `new`. Did you allocate anything by `new` in this code? No. So, stop trying to `delete` anything.

Objects `foo` and `vertices` are local objects with *automatic* storage duration. The memory for these objects is allocated automatically and freed automatically. You cannot do it yourself. This is completely outside of your control.

If you want to control memory allocation manually, you have to create these objects dynamically, using `new`. For example

```
std::array<int, 3> *foo = new std::array<int, 3>();
...
(*foo)[0] = 1;
(*foo)[1] = 2;
(*foo)[2] = 3;
...
delete foo;
```

The above will work. But there's no real reason to involve dynamic memory in your example. It works perfectly fine as is, with automatic objects. Just stop trying to `delete` them.

`delete` expects a *pointer* as argument. When you will allocate objects through `new`, you will access these objects through pointers. These pointers is what you will later pass to `delete` to destroy such objects. In this code none of this is applicable.

Comment: What if the content of the std::array is an object pointer. Like "std::array<Object*, 10> myArray1;".. If it was "Object *myArray2[10];", then I would be able to call "delete []myArray2;", and it would also call destructor of the Object instances. Can I call "delete []myArray1;" ?

Comment: @phoad: I'm not sure I understand your comment. If `myArray2` was declared as  `Object *myArray2[10]`, then you would **not** be able to do `delete[] myArray2`.

Comment: I have remembered as "delete[] arr;" would call destructor of each object in the "arr" and deallocate them. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/ "operator delete[] is a regular function that can be called explicitly just as any other function. But in C++, delete[] is an operator with a very specific behavior: An expression with the delete[] operator, first calls the appropriate destructors for each element in the array (if these are of a class type), and then calls an array deallocation function.". Should it be Object arr[] = new Object[10], instead of Object* arr[] ?